# How to get a particular element of an xml in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to obtain historic data from the ECB exchange rate site. They publish (https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml) the last 90 days of data in the form of xml, like this:

[90 days xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQvCe.png)

However, I just need the latest day from there.

I am downloading the whole xml data and with a dataflow I intend to get only the latest day and transform it to have a JSON file at the end. I have the following dataflow:

[dataflow and xml source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14sJS.png)

I have a flat activity to get the dates and their associated currencies and rates:

[flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxuLc.png)

But I just need the entries for the latest day:

[just want the latest date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXSOt.png)

Can I add a previous step to the Flat activity to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I just need the entries for the latest day

To achieve your requirement, you need to first get the latest date and the then compare your data with the latest date.

1. First you need take Aggregate transformation to get the latest date from the `max()` function
   [image]
   Data Preview:
   [image]
2. Now add another Source in dataflow with same source dataset and flatten it similar to you above dataset and add exist transformation to compare the data with latest date we got by Aggregate transformation and get only those data where date and latest date is matching.
   [image]

**Output:**

[image]